# Hot water doesn't reach the 2nd floor

Tags: water, temperature

My house is 90+ years old. It has an oil burner which supplies radiator heat and hot water. No water tank, hot water created on the fly. The basement and first floor water gets hot enough, but the 2nd floor water in the shower & sink does not.
It starts hot, but remains warm for a less than a minute if the furnace has been running, but then cools off quickly. It gets slightly warmer again after about 8 minutes of running (and the furnace kicks on). I changed the mixing valve in the shower last year - although the sink having the same problem negates that shower valve as the culprit. I can mitigate the  cooler water temp by turning up the temperature setting on furnace's hot water temp gauge - but I really don't like doing this because I have to run it at 215 degrees and then the radiators are burning hot, even if the room thermostat is set below the room temp. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: **Oil burning on demand hot water ?**  Something does not seem right here. Can elaborate on the system you have, perhaps some photos. Did it work fine and then something changed. More info is needed.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: It never was an ideal set-up, I think with a tankless hot water system, you never get consistently heated water, but I got a new boiler and furnace about 7 years ago, and since then it was limited in the amount of hot water it delivered. It does seem to be worse this winter and I think its because the system is getting older.

Comment: @SeymourHymen You still have not told us what system you have, Is there a manufacturer and model number ? And explain why the heating system and the hot water supply are connected. Even More info is needed.